# IntelliJ does not detect struts 2 and tiles, can't create fileset

Tags: intellij-idea, struts2

Today I created a new Maven multi-module project from scratch with IntelliJ 2016.2 and archetypes `pom-root` and `apache-struts2-starter`. I have been working on several Struts 2 projects with tiles now so I know about the struts 2 file sets, the auto detection of frameworks, etc.

Strange thing now with this new project: IntelliJ doesn't detect anything. I was waiting for this little pop up which says "Struts 2 detected, configure" where I can create a fileset with all struts xml files, but nothing happens. Also I can't create a fileset myself in the facet window in the settings. If I try, no files to add are shown.

On the other hand, IntelliJ does show me the Struts 2 facet, but I can't manage to configure it properly in IntelliJ. I don't understand why it works for another project, but not for this new one. So I'm not able to jump from one tiles result to its definition, or from a JSP with struts:action to its action definition in `struts.xml`...

I can build and run the project perfectly, but why does IntelliJ not configure it?

Comment: Where's the location of `struts.xml`?

Comment: Usual default location, `src/resources`.

Comment: My miststake, i meant src/main/resources.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the problem had to do with the doctype (more exact: the dtd) in my struts.xml. Usually it is something like

`<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">`

But, because I selected the newest Struts-2-Version for this new project, I thought it had the be

`<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.5//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.5.dtd">`

corresponding to the struts-version 2.5.2 (general question: how do I know which doctype i have to use??). It seems that the Ijntellij-Struts-Plugin doesn't "recognize" this DTD-Version (although it does exist, see http://struts.apache.org/dtds/). If I change it to 2.3 or 2.1, the small popup "No file sets configured" immediately appears. Very strange.

Comment: Update: Apparently it is not the DTD-Url, but the first Version in the doctype:

It has to be 
`-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN`

instead of


`-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.5//EN`

I don't know why,

Comment: Still got the problem though that I can't properly configure filesets. It shows me only my struts.xml, but not the ones from the lib (struts-default.xml, struts-plugin.xml)...

Also Intellij still won't let me jump into `extends="struts-default"` in the package definitition or jump into JSPs which I reference as an action-result. I don't get how Intellij configures this differently than another, older project I'm working on, where all the references are clickable.